# In PHP, how to quickly access objects property from a return?

Tags: php, object

My problem is this.

A function return an object, and I want to access its property. It throws and error when I try to do it like this

```
$this->FunctionThatReturnsAnObject()->Property;
```

Right now I'm creating a new variable and taking the property from it, like this:

```
$newVar=$this->FunctionThatReturnsAnObject();
$property=$newVar->Property;
```

Is this the right way of doing this?

Comment: What error does it throw in what PHP version?

Comment: PHP 5 allows chaining, but PHP 4 does not. If you have PHP 5 and it still doesn't work, perhaps the function is a constructor - but from your code snippet that doesn't appear to be the case. It might help if you posted the actual code.

Comment: And what is the error, or should we be psychic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works perfectly fine in modern PHP versions.

```
[mcg@mcg-workstation ~]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > class Foo { public function functionThatReturnsAnObject() { return new Bar(); } }
php > class Bar { public $property = 'Hello, world.'; }
php > $f = new Foo();
php > echo $f->functionThatReturnsAnObject()->property;
Hello, world.
php >
```

If you're experiencing an error, we'll need to know what the error is.  As mentioned in the comments, you might not be able to do this in PHP4, but you shouldn't be using PHP4 in the modern era to begin with.  As long as the *instance method* you're calling returns an object, you can operate on that object directly.  (You can't do this from a constructor right now: `new Foo()->functionThatReturnsAnObject()` will not work because the PHP internals team is full of people that think this would be confusing in some way.  I'm not making this up.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem was, that the function was returning an instance instead of an object. My bad.